# Is possible to use pixy like normal camera

Tags: c++, arduino

I have got pixy(CMUcam5). Is possible to get matrix from camera or something similar without reconding precoded code from charmed labs ?

Comment: "reconding precoded code"? What does that mean?

Comment: Recoding libraries for pixy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't.
In pixy forums there are several people asking for video feed and the answers from the developers is that there is not one.

It's possible that in a future version of the firmware it will be available but not in a near future